# Attaching an unpublished draft on the CV

Tags: graduate-admissions, cv, research-undergraduate

**Background:** CS undergrad applying to CS PhD FALL 2022

I am working on a project but don't think I will be able to publish it before I send out my admits. I am planning to just attach a draft on my CV.

**Question:**

1. Is this something one should do?
2. Or should I just mention it without any draft?

I am going to talk about the project in brief on my SOP. That's why I want to attach it.

Comment: Any reason you can't put in on arxiv?

Comment: Putting it on arxiv might prevent me from submitting it to a conference later. That's why I want to avoid that.

Comment: @GoodDeeds arxiv is not meant to hold drafts of work. I would only ever put publication-ready material on there.

Comment: Yes, the draft I will be attaching will be the exact copy of the publication ready document.

Comment: @astronat Of course, you're right, I just incorrectly assumed that the work was publication ready.

Comment: @astronat I do the same, but some people do put rough drafts on ArXiv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the CV, you can mention it under 'Working Papers', and yes, attach the document as a separate file  to the application.

Comment: Thank you for this. It's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Many (but not all) PhD applications specifically ask for a writing sample. The exact requirements can vary, but in my experience unpublished drafts are typically acceptable. That would be an ideal approach to share your work with them.

Otherwise, if they don't ask for a writing sample or allow attaching additional documents, **do not try to use a trojan horse**. When they ask for a CV, they expect *just* a CV. However impressive your paper may be, it probably won't outweigh ignoring their fairly direct instructions.

If they don't provide any official way to share it, then I completely agree with anpami and recommend listing/linking it within your CV. It's common to have a section for publications and (now that soft copies are standard) a link makes it easy for anyone who actually wants to look at it.

Comment: Thank you for this !! I'll keep that in mind!